# Which MDA_EXTERNAL parameters should I use in GetMail for Zimbra?

Tags: zimbra

I need your knowledge, I have a Zimbra server internally that works correctly, but I have an external server and I would like to download the mails, I see that I can use GetMail, but the doubt I have is with the `MDA_EXTERNAL` what are the parameters to use to download the mails and leave them in the user's mailbox in Zimbra.

Thanks

```
[retriever]
type = SimplePOP3Retriever
server = pop.example.net
username = jeff.plotzky
password = mailpassword

[destination]
type = MDA_external
path = /opt/zimbra/common/sbin/postfix
user = zimbra
group zimbra
```